# What is the most efficient way to make triangles?

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

I need to make 500 Billion triangles.  My best machine so far makes 16,000,000 every second.

[image: Grid]

Is there a better way to make more triangles?

Comment: That's a new update.  Bigger than 5x5 allowed now?

Comment: @Frank After getting past a certain point in the Quest you are given a bigger grid to build with.  I do not remember when that was, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the solution is simple. I just started today and already my resources are something like 5x10^25 per second. You need Puzzlers. Your first line looks good, but instead of transmuting it you add puzzlers. Puzzlers double the input out the front, and subtract the input on the bottom. Normally this means no net gain, but if you block the negative side it works like a normal double. The puzzlers go all the way to the right except the last spot, block this with a sink. The puzzler before has a negative input on the bottom, use a corner piece here and send it right back through uncoilers. Loop.

The best thing about this design? Those 2 Conduit (B)'s allow me to change 1 of them to an uncoiler, and make a RAPID resource sink to satisfy the pope. Obviously the far top right is where a coiler goes. It is currently turned off!

[image]